# Install MEncoder in Ubuntu

Tags: mencoder, ubuntu-13.04

I am trying to install MEncoder on Ubuntu 13.04. I tried -> sudo apt-get install mencoder but the following error is coming:

`Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree

Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package mencoder`

I tried to find static builds but could not find. Anyone knows the solution?

Answer (score -1):

Yesterday i downloaded mencoder in my ubuntu 14.04 for combining 4 flv files and was struggling as you are. 
What helped me is the link :http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/medibuntu_non_free/raring/non-free/base/mencoder.

Go there and directly install mencoder from there.
Check if this helps.